# problem in install Unity theme

Tags: themes

I tried to install new themes for unity desktop and i found this topic in search

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/first-unity-theme-created-available-for-download/

and follow all steps but i faced this problem after write command update (apt-get update)

get this error

[image: problem]

> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/isantop/iansanto-ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

and after command installation this

> apt-get install unity-theme

and faced this problem

> E: Unable to locate package unity-theme

What is the reason؟

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is only for Ubuntu 11.04 (Published March 20, 2011) so you need to remove this repository open the Ubuntu software center and then press `Edit and Software Sources...`
find this repository `ppa:isantop/iansanto-ppa` and press the remove button to delete it

Comment: i doubt in that too okay man i will do that thank you